# Base64 string not showing completely in VS Code Terminal using Python syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to do python programming and currently extracting data from a mongoDB database. the data is in base64 format and i am trying to get the whole string. Unfortunately, only 8303 out of 133728 characters are shown in VS Code terminal when I execute the code.

Is there a setting in VS Code to show the complete base64 string?

Any recommendation will help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The content in the terminal is called the buffer, with the section right above the bottom viewport being called "scrollback". The amount of scrollback kept is determined by the terminal.integrated.scrollback setting and defaults to 1000 lines. Go to settings (file->preferences->settings), search for terminal.integrated.scrollback and change it.

Comment: No terminal allows infinite scrollback. All of them, on all OSs, have a limited buffer. If you want to inspect such a large string, write it to a file and open it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about vscode, but for an output that big it would probably be more convenient to write it to a file.
Assuming the variable that holds your data is called `result`, you can try something like:

```py
with open("result_data", "w") as result_data_file:
    result_data_file.write(result["resulttext"])
```

Comment: All terminals limit how many lines are kept in a buffer. Terminals aren't file editors or viewers

Comment: Thanks for this idea. but in case i will pull 1000+ base64 records, does it mean i need to put them to a text file one by one or is there other way to do it?

Comment: @JayvenJavier Depends on what you want to do with that data I'd say :-). You could write each in a different file, send them to a database, or perform the operations you need to in memory and never write them anywhere etc... Multiple approaches are possible depending on what it is you need to do

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can increase the limit on the number of characters that can be displayed in the VS Code terminal:

1. Open the VSCode settings and search for **terminal.integrated.scrollback**.

[image]

2. You can modify the value to a higher number.
3. Save the settings and restart VSCode.

After increasing the `terminal.integrated.scrollback` setting, you should be able to see more characters in the VS Code terminal when you execute your code.